# Have to re-plug speaker jack input to get sound

Tags: sound, audio-jack

Every time I log in to Ubuntu 15.10, the external speakers do not produce any sound at all.  I always have to replug the input jack to get sound.  It is not that crucial, but it would be great if this problem can be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of issues can be avoided by using 14.04 LTS version of Ubuntu instead of 15.10. I tried the later and it had so many bugs in my experience whereas with 14.04 I experience no issues at all. Ubuntu website also states that 14.04 is "Recommended for most users".

Anyway, Ubuntu has a great program called **PulseAudio Volume Control** from Ubuntu Software Center. You can try fixing your sound configuration with this app:

1. In application's "Output Devices" tab choose default output device by pressing green button (device which is not selected will be default, not the opposite).
2. Try changing "Port" in the same tab (usually it will be a choice between headphones and speakers).
3. Choose suitable profile in "Configuration" tab.
4. You can also choose settings per specific application, 1) play music with chosen application 2) and go to "Playback" tab where you can select suitable device for that application and its settings.

I think in the process of tuning the configuration you may solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it first. If it doesn't solve it, i guess i will use the lts version. Thanks

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the problem's gone. Thank you